# Android Studio build java.exe suspended second time around

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, gradle, build

Using Android Studio 3.1.4 on Windows 64 Pro.
When running any app, including a sample project, Android Studio gets stuck the second time around on build/run cycle.

In Windows task manager I see java.exe suspended where one of the process threads it says is waiting on network i/o.

I have to kill java.exe from the Windows task manager every time I build/run an app.

I tried all of the following with no help:

- deleted .gradle in my user folder
- deleted .AndroidStudio3.1 folder in my user folder
- invalidate caches/restart
- use offline gradle option
- disable instant run

Any ideas why this is happening? Seems that the build process is deadlocking on itself. This only happens on the second build/run.

Comment: Hi Farid, I am encountering the exact same problem. Did you managed to resolved?

Comment: Hi Ed, no resolution to this issue so far, as far as I know, except for killing java.exe every time you want to rebuild/run an app in AS. I logged a bug report for it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117145266

Answer (score 1):

I've used Sysinternals ProcessExplorer. In the context menu you can just RESUME the java process and the build will work

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue and have tried re-installs, differing JVMs, and countless other tactics. As a temporary workaround I have modified the Gradle build to create a flag file which a separate Powershell script then polls for and if found kills any running Open JDK process. This is a kludge without doubt but helps keep me sane.

Update build.gradle(Module:app) to include the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ...
    }
    android.applicationVariants.all {
        ant.touch(file:"D:/Build.flg")
    }
}
```

Then run the following Powershell script

```
do {
    Write-Host "Checking for D:\Build.flg"
    if (Test-Path "D:\Build.flg") {
        Remove-Item "D:\Build.flg"
        Write-Host "Locating Java processes"
        $JavaProcessos = Get-Process java | select Id, processname, Description
        Foreach($Process in $JavaProcessos)
        {
            if($Process.Description -eq "OpenJDK Platform binary") {
                Write-Host "Stopping process " $Process.Id $Process.Description
                Start-Sleep -s 30
                Stop-Process $Process.Id
            }
        }   
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 10
}
While ($true)
```

Not pretty but functional.

I could not call the script directly from the build as it kills the JVM that Gradle itself is using at the time - thus the delay and flag approach.

I welcome suggestions to improve, until the root cause is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of trying to fix the Android Studio alternate build hang, I damaged my Eclipse / Python install. Surprisingly, fixing Eclipse also seems to have eliminated the Android build problem. Came down to setting the right Java environment variables.

Press the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key and search for [Edit the system environment variables].

Then add / update the following based on the location of your JDK installation.

```
CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
JDK_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre
```

Finally, add the Java bin to the start of your path

```
Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...
```

After this my Android Studio builds no longer hang and Eclipse is fully functional.

Comment: I had high hopes, but this did not help. Any other ideas?